# Configure ETag Filter in Java Web.xml properly?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, etag

I am creating a Java filter to handling ETag for my web application.

Here is my code:

```
<!-- language: java -->

public class ETagFilter implements Filter {

   public doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {

     if ( (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) == false ) {
         chain.doFilter(request, response);
     } else {

          ETagResponseWrapper wrapper = new ETagResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse)response);

          filterChain.doFilter(request, wrapper);

          byte[] body = wrapper.toByteArray();
          // ....
          // Other process
     }         
}
```

}

in WEB.xml. I configure my ETagFilter like this

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ETagFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>myapp.ETagFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ETagFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

If I configure my filter like above. ONLY request with DispatcherType is REQUEST handled by the Filter. Other request with dispatcher types like FORWARD, INCLUDE, ERROR, ASYNC will NOT handled by ETagFilter.

My question is:  Do I have to add other dispatcher types (FORWARD, INCLUDE, ERROR, ASYNC) into my etag filter mapping in order to configure my ETagFilter correctly? (like below)

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ETagFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>
 </filter-mapping>
```

In my opinion. REQUEST is enough. How about your ideas. Thanks,

Comment: It depends on what your application does. If you are serving an `*.html` document through a `forward`, then having an `ETagFilter` on it might be useful.

Comment: .html does means STATIC html document. You can think the mapping extension can be .abc. How about other dispatcher types like INCLUDE, ERROR, ASYNC?

Comment: Yes, but your `url-pattern` is set to `*.html`, so it'll be filtering, for example, `forward` requests for something that fits that pattern. I would say the same applies for all the types.

Comment: Let say INCLUDE. A caller servlet including another servlet using Include dispatcher. In other servet, we process: response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_MODIFIED) if resource is NOT Modified and NOT write any content into response. In Calling servlet, we will not get response return by the other servlet. Will this be an issue?

Comment: You will probably have issues in that case. Note that an ETag is meant for a resource, not for a path. If you have a resource that is rendered by a component that some times includes it in other resources, then that ETag probably doesn't apply to the other resources.